# How to update monthly/annual records

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

Alright, I've been trying for days but I really don't know the code and i'm seeking help.

My problem:

I'm making a program that will collect and update data on each members donation/tithes. Members donate weekly, then the database table has Weekly, Monthly and Annual Column. Now, I need to know how to update the Monthly and Annual column while still keeping the weekly record. Because every time I add a new record the monthly and annual column does now update.

Code so far:

```
Private Sub btnAddOffertory_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddOffertory.Click
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblOffertory(ID, Name, Weekly, Date, Monthly, Annual)VALUES(@ID, @Name, @Weekly, @Date, @Monthly, @Annual)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = DGOList.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = DGOList.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Weekly", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = txtOffertory.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = dtpOffertory.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Monthly", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 0
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Annual", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = 0
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    If (i > 0) Then
        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE tblOffertory SET Monthly += @Monthly WHERE Date = '" & dtpOffertory.Text & "' AND ID = " & DGOList.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Monthly", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = txtOffertory.Text
        End Using
    End If
    cn.Close()
    ShowORecord()
    OClear()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result

Comment: EEK!!!! You did such a nice job parmeterizing your insert statement but then you opened the door to sql injection in that update. You should parameterize ALL of your queries. Even worse in that update is that you parameterized some of it.

Comment: Something seems a bit off in your structure here. You are keeping track of how much money people donate but in the same table you are tracking aggregate data. I would suggest that you simply track the donations and make a view, or possibly a computed column, to hold the values of the aggregate data. Storing it side by side in the same table is painful.

Comment: @GuidoG, I don't know how to comment pictures here so i'll just explain. An expected result should be like. A person donates $100 every week on month of sept, then so there's $100 in every row in all of the person's entry in the weekly column then $400 in the monthly as well as the annual. then the monthly column would have have $0 on the next month. something like that. sorry if it's not very clear

Comment: @SeanLange, could you aggregate for me. I don't understand what it is. and could you give me a sample table on how to properly do it? thanks

Comment: @SeanLange and also how to properly parameterize the update statement. thank you!

Comment: For a good example of a parameterized query you need look further than your own code. You need to parameterize the predicate values in your where clause.

Comment: The problem you are facing here is this "there's $100 in every row in all of the person's entry in the weekly column then $400 in the monthly as well as the annual". This is a horrible design. This data is an aggregate (if you don't understand that term you need to look it up). As such it should be stored in a summary table or create a view that will aggregate the data on demand. Storing this in every row is a clear indication that your table is not properly normalized. We do not want to store the same value over and over...that is the basis of 1NF.